# Django как рендерить js файл?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django

Пробую делать так:

```
url(
    regex=r'^(?P<jsfile>[^/]+).js/$',
    view=views.JSfileDetailView.as_view(),
    name='detail'
),
```

С таким `views`:

```
class JSfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = JSfile
    #pk_url_kwarg = 'jsfile' 
    slug_field = 'jsfile'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'jsfile'
    template_name = 'jsfiles/jsfile_detail.js'
```

Пытаясь отрендерить просто `js`, на выходе он получается внутри тега `<body></body>`, и естественно, его не возможно использовать как `js`

Как быть ? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было всего лишь указать `content_type`:

```
class JSfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = JSfile
    #pk_url_kwarg = 'jsfile' 
    slug_field = 'jsfile'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'jsfile'
    template_name = 'jsfiles/jsfile_detail.js' 
    content_type = 'application/javascript'
```

Узнал [здесь](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/)